# How run python script with arguments from powershell as admin

Tags: python, windows, powershell

There are various threads on this subject but nothing that seems to help with my specific case.  I'm not a Windows user normally though so maybe I'm missing something.

I need to run a series of python scripts, with arguments, from a single Windows (2016) powershell script.  The python scripts must be run as administrator (as they need access to the local registry).

I've got as far as this, based on stuff in other threads on the subject:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }


& python.exe V:Scripts\script.py --hostnames del rodney
```

This launches a subshell as administrator, but that subshell fails when running the python script.  The subshell disappears before I have chance to see the error message, but the powershell event log states "Engine state is changed from Available to Stopped" which I believe suggests it is a permissions error.

The python script works fine if run directly from an administrator powershell.  Any pointers gratefully accepted.

Comment: Try using -NoExit to find the actual error message :)

Comment: Thanks this shows that the problem is that the python interpreter apparently can't find the script, although it's definitely there: "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'V:\Scripts\script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".   Quoting it makes no difference.

Comment: It's crazy because in that subshell that throws the error, I can then run "python.exe V:Scripts\script.py" and it works.  So that shell can find the file, but it can't when run in the way I'm doing it.

Comment: My bad.  Typo (not replicated in example above as I'd redacted sensitive stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking if the current powershell session is running as administrator, then if not it it is running another session as adminstrator.

However your python code is still running in the initial Poweshell session (which is not running as administrator).

Modify your code as follows:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command ""python.exe V:Scripts\script.py --hostnames del rodney""" -Verb RunAs
} else {
    python.exe V:Scripts\script.py --hostnames del rodney
}
```

This will check if the current session is running as administrator, it will run the python code directly; If it is not, it will run new Powershell session as administrator and run the python code in it.